# Nested SQL statements in Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

the output that I want to achieve is something like this:

```
A
    Anthony SL
        Cars Project
        Flyers printing
        Projekt 3
C
    Carl SL
        Painting job
```

Basically an alphabethic index of customers and their related projects.

The customers I have them in a table called "tx_myclients" and the projects I have them as pages. So this is what Im doing http://pastebin.com/tfknf16Z

but for some reason seems like the inner select stops the loop on the outer ones. What could I do? Cant I have nested SQL statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. But I think it's intentional that the same record of the same table is not being rendered twice.

For that matter, the rendering information is being stored in (123 is the uid of that client):

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->recordRegister['tx_myclients:123']
```

Take a look at `typo3/sysext/cms/tslib/content/class.tslib_content_content.php`, around line 134ff

To solve this to could  XCLASS `tslib_content_Content` or create a view in MySQL which shows your data as a different table:

```
CREATE VIEW tx_myclients_view
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM tx_myclients
```

I'm sure there are tons of other workarounds to that.

---

### Edit

For the view part (that's easier than a XCLASS):

- Use the above SQL statement in your MySQL tool
- Replace the table / view names with the names matching your table (The view has to start with `tx_` as well)
- Now you'll have a 'table' in your MySQL database which is an exact 'copy'(*) of your real table, just with a different name
- select the first loop from `tx_myclients` and the second one from `tx_myclients_view`, so both have independent caches

(* It's not really a copy, it's acting as a table. When you select from it,  it runs the select statement from the `CREATE VIEW` statement. 
In other words, if you CRUD on the original, it's reflected in the view. [Read more in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html))

Comment: I hope so, because I have no idea what an XCLASS or a VIEW is :(

Comment: @Dbugger: I've updated my answer and added a detailed explanation about the `VIEW` solution

Comment: Using a "copy" of the table works? As you see in my example I use 2 different tables, "tx_myclients" and "pages" and that also stops the outer loop...